# postgresql dynamic variable reference

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

i m trying to write a function which returns the chosen variable value dynamically as follows.

```
create function get_constval(constname text) 
returns text
language plpgsql
as
$$
  declare 
     alpha varchar(100):= 'This is alpha value'; 
     beta  varchar(100):= 'This is beta  value';
     constval varchar(100);
  begin
     constval:=constname;
     return constval;
  end;
$$
```

when i run the code
select get_constval('alpha')  it returns 'alpha' and not 'This is alpha value'
is there a way to eval the variable and return the value dynamically ?

Thanks,
NSR

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, that is not possible.

You could do something like that with `jsonb`:

```
DO
$$DECLARE
   vars jsonb := '{ "alpha": "This is alpha value", "beta": "This is beta  value" }';
   constval text;
   constname text := 'alpha';
BEGIN
   EXECUTE 'SELECT ($1)->>$2' INTO constval
      USING vars, constname;
   RAISE NOTICE 'constval = ''%''', constval;
END;$$;

NOTICE:  constval = 'This is alpha value'
DO
```